# android setVisibility ui display strangely

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

**My english is poor,if you don't understand what I mean,please tell me,thanks.**

My data stored in SQLiteDatabase,I use listview to show my data.and I implement collapse/expand myself via ListActivity.onItemClick(). but when childview.setVisibility(View.GONE),sometimes android ui show half, I'm new user of stack overflow, and I can't post images.

1)default display:expanded all groups

The images link to another website,

2)[collapsed all groups](http://mblogpic.store.qq.com/mblogpic/926b9b102c63023bf154/460)

3)[when several times clicked on listview's item,the main activity showed only half of window height](http://mblogpic.store.qq.com/mblogpic/2c4422cc604cf0ba2a4c/460)

what's wrong with my solution. or it's android bug?

this is code:

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list,View v,int position,long id) {
        if(v instanceof RelativeLayout) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)v;
            ImageView groupIndicator = (ImageView) group.getChildAt(0);
            TextView itemContentView = (TextView) group.getChildAt(2);
            if(itemContentView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                groupIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.expand);
                itemContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                groupIndicator.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.collapse);
                itemContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is listview's layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="@drawable/corner"
  android:padding="3dip"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/groupIndicator" android:background="@drawable/expand" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/rowTitle" android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/groupIndicator" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/rowContent" android:layout_below="@id/groupIndicator" android:padding="5dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use an ExpandableListView. Instead of onListItemClick you will use onGroupClickListener.

read the doc here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html